# How to access Google Cloud Storage from dockerfile

Tags: google-cloud-storage, dockerfile

I am trying to download some files from google cloud storage but I don't know nor how to login inside the dockerfile build neither if I need to create an IAM role for this specific task.

Can you please provide some help? Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the permission, you have to be able to list and download from the bucket ([project owner/editor](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions) or [storage admin/objectAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles)). I did not check all of them, but these work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gsutil from within docker.
To try this first in 'interactive' mode you could do something like the following:

```
docker run -it google/cloud-sdk:alpine
gcloud auth login
gsutil -m cp /some-file gs://your-bucket
```

Comment: Hi Mike, any idea on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969644/copy-files-from-gcs-into-a-cloud-run-docker-container-during-build/